# Installing OpenGL and OpenAL in Ubuntu

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, openal

How can I install OpenGL (with GLUT) and OpenAL (with ALUT) in Ubuntu Lucid lynx? I tried installing Mesa 7.8.2 using configure and make (the method told in www.mesa3d.org), but it is not installing anything. X.org's X is installed in my system, but there is no /usr/X11R6 directory. Is that a problem?

Comment: Try asking this on http://unix.stackexchange.com, they might be able to help

Comment: [Setting up OpenGL on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7842622/608639)

Answer (score 33):

```
    sudo apt-get update
    OpenGL: sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
    OpenAL: sudo apt-get install libopenal0a libopenal-dev
    ALUT:   sudo apt-get install libalut0 libalut-dev
```

[ALUT may have broken packages but it works fine]

Comment: Instead of **libopenal0a**, try **libopenal1**.

Comment: ^ comment above worked.