# Error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.1.10: cannot open shared object file

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, opengl, glew

I'm trying to work on an OpenGL project at home on my Linux PC.

I got this error when launching my OpenGL project with "./executable"

I have already installed libglew-dev package, and also I can't find the file "libGLEW.so.1.10" in my directories.

I don't know how I could install it in the right place.

Comment: Yes, it is ubuntu

Comment: How was the executable built? And where?

Comment: [Setting up OpenGL on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7842622/608639), [Installing OpenGL and OpenAL in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3907064/608639), [How do I set up an OpenGL programming environment?](https://askubuntu.com/q/11378), [How to install OpenGL/GLUT libraries](https://askubuntu.com/q/96087), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dev` package provides headers and source for you to, well, `dev`elop with.

Now, on the target machine, you need to install the normal package that provides the shared libraries.

The Ubuntu package list has [some candidates](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libglew): from your question it looks like you're using v1.10, so `libglew1.10`.

The documentation has some ways to [do it manually](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html) without a package manager.

Comment: `libglew2.0` on this Debian Stable box, [same on Ubuntu looks like](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libglew2.0).

Comment: @genpfault Probably `libglew1.10` based on the package list and the name of the `.so` being searched for

Comment: Ah, good point, I glossed over that.

Comment: @genpfault Me too :P

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, i've download the libglew1.10 package from the internet and my project launched. I did not think of taking the 1.10 instead of 2.0 version. thanks really

Comment: @Djinnmercure Have fun